# Python Thread is not working simultaniously

Tags: python, multithreading, server, mqtt

I'm currently working with python and want to receive data via MQTT and later send it to a server. When I receive a "0" then I want to start a timer, which should run in the background so I still can get data and send it to a server. I start the timer with a thread but in my case the program stops till the timer is over and then continues with the receive and send.

**Code:**

```python
import threading
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
     client.subscribe("test/test/projekt")

def timer_started():
     global timer_thread
     print("timer started")
     shutdown_timer = time.time()
     elapsed = 0
     while elapsed < 5:
          elapsed = time.time()-shutdown_timer
     print("Timer finished")

def on_message(client, userdata,msg):
     global thread_active 
     if msg.payload =="0" and thread_active == False:
           thread_active =True
           global timer_thread
           timer_thread.start()

timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=timer_started)
client=mqtt.CLient()
client.on_connect() = on_connect
client.on_message= on_message
client.connect("test.mosquitto.org",1883,60)
client.loop_forever()
```

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable thread_active and comparison of msg.payload might be the is culprit. MQTT payload needs to be converted to string before comparing it. I did a check for the above code with modification it could receive data while in timer thread.

Below is the working example:

```
import threading
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('connection')
    print (rc)
    client.subscribe("Test")

def timer_started():
    global timer_thread, thread_active
    print("timer started")
    shutdown_timer = time.time()
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < 5:
        elapsed = time.time()-shutdown_timer
    print("Timer finished")
    thread_active =False

def on_message(client, userdata,msg):
    print("Message")
    print(msg.payload)
    global thread_active
    if msg.payload.decode("utf-8") =="0" and thread_active == False:
        thread_active =True
        global timer_thread
        timer_thread.start()


timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=timer_started)
thread_active = False
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("localhost",1883,60)
client.loop_forever()
```

On publishing the dummy topic 'Test' value with '0', timer gets started and during the timer run for a check, '5' is published to the same topic. Below is the output as expected to run:

```
connection
0
Message
b'0'
timer started
Message
b'5'
Timer finished
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. But on my device this didnt work well. If i publish one message when the timer has started it worked but if i published more then there was no print and only after the timer finished the console printed, that it received a message.

Comment: Wait a minute i tested it again with a little diffrence. When the timer started i send messages from from the client to the server and the server received them but there where no prints to the console. Is it to much work to print out what it received or is there somthing fishy?  But that only worked if i printed something in the timer_started method while the timer ist running... I don't understand what is happening there...

Comment: Ok I guess I figured it out. I added a 0.5 second sleep to the timer thread and then it does what i wanted. My Question is now: is it true that there is no process change, when i do a while method with no interruptions ? :D

Comment: @benipro I am not able to understand, are you not able to get multiple messages when published to a topic. If there is any particular use case when it is not working, pls describe it using minimum working example and output you get in that case. Glad it helped !

Comment: when the timer started my console just printed out "timer started" and after that didn t printed, that more messages had been received until the timer was done. After that it printed all the messages that it got during that time.

Comment: @benipro i did checked the script in terminal and it printed the message during execution of timer. In your case problem might not be related to code. It works as expected.